# set uniform weight on component

Tags: armature, bones, weight-painting

I am struggling on one simple task. I want to set weight of an object. When I assign a bone to it, Blender gives it a random weight map. I want 1.0 everywhere, but whatever I press nothing happens. I also tried painting manually but, although I don't like the method, it doesn't work either.
Thanks in advance.

[image: this is one example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of mechanical weight-assignment..

Through the 'Vertex Groups' panel in the object's Data tab

- Select the vertices whose weights you want to modify
- With the relevant group selected in the panel, set the value in the slider beneath it, and hit 'Assign'.

**Or**, in Edit mode, Vertex.. ( it might help to have 'Vertex Group Weights' checked in the Overlays, to see the weights as colors)

- **If** the  active vertex is in an existing vertex group, then the Vertex Weights  dropdown will appear, as shown

[image]

- Set the weight of the active vertex, in the indicated group.
- Hit 'Copy' to copy the weight to the other selected vertices

**Or**, in Weight Paint mode..

[image]

- With Vertex Masking switched on, and having tabbed out to make your vertex selection and back again, if necessary
- Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> to fill the selection with the current Brush setting.